# Unsupported Operand Types Python Power and Lists

Tags: python, arrays

One of the tutorial questions has us focus on creating a function which returns a simple expression. The expression is below:

EQ = cos*(pi/2)*x^2 + sin(pi/4)*x + x^3
Where x is an array of floats.

I have written the following code to answer this:

```
def  getStats(x):
    # Complete the function.    
    y = float(numpy.cos((numpy.pi/2)*x**2) + numpy.sin((numpy.pi/4)*x) + x**3) 
return y
```

However I get an error saying unsupported operand types for pow or ** list or int.

I have tried to type cast this but it has not worked.
Apart from type casting I have tried breaking this down further but have been unsuccessful. Any ideas on what I can try next?

Thank you.

Comment: what are you passing to the function? And please avoid posting images. Paste the text instead.

Comment: I am passing an array in the form of [1.0,2.0,3.0]

Comment: and what do you expect the result of `[1.0,2.0,3.0]**2` (`x**2`) to be? You cannot raise a `list` to a power.

Comment: Try using the numpy.power() function instead of `**`. Also, convert the list to an array, it's a list at this point.

Comment: I have tried doing this:
y = numpy.power((numpy.cos((numpy.pi/2)*x),2)) + (numpy.sin((numpy.pi/4)*x)) + (numpy.power(x,3))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should evaluate the expression for each value of the input list. You can do this using list comprehension.

```
def  getStats(X):
    # Complete the function.
    y = [float(numpy.cos((numpy.pi/2)*x**2) + numpy.sin((numpy.pi/4)*x) + x**3) for x in X]
    return y
```

The approach in the **edit** section is preferred (see below).

---

**Edit**: Converting the input list to numpy array and do the computation.

```
def  getStats(x):
    # Complete the function.
    x = numpy.array(x)
    y = numpy.cos((numpy.pi/2) * numpy.power(x, 2)) + numpy.sin((numpy.pi/4)*x) + numpy.power(x, 3)
    return y # if you want to return a list, use list(y)
```

Comment: Given we're in numpy land anyway, doesn't it make sense to just `x = np.array(X)` before calculating `y` instead of going through a list comprehension?